# Dynamically reposition tables in report to replace invisible tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report which has 4 similar sized tables. Currently I control the visibility of each table based on an expression which works fine but when say the top most table doesn't appear it leaves a gap at the top of my report. Is there some way to get the report to reposition whatever tables are visible so that they appear neatly without gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the tables in Rectangles and set the visibility of the Rectangles the same as the tables.

Make sure all the Rectangles are exactly adjacent to each other and that each table is at the top of the Rectangle.

When a Rectangle is hidden, it should also hide any whitespace in the Rectangle too, i.e. the next Rectangle (and hence the related table) will appear without gaps.

Comment: Cool, sounds easy. I'll give it a go and report back.